# How to do optimization in HBase partial scanning

Tags: hbase

I want to perform scan on HBase table having 4 billion records and each record is of size ~500 bytes. I am expecting each scan will return records up to 500K records and in size ~250MB.

Table name: **Transaction** 
**Column Family: cf** 
Column qualifier in cf: transactionTime, citycode, userid, amount, discount amount, phoneNumber, email

RowKey structure: salt_userid_citycode_phoneNumber_transactionTime

I have to scan all transaction of a given citycode.

My **STARTROW**: salt_citycode

**ENDROW**: salt_(citycode+1)

```
Scan scanRequest = new Scan();
scanRequest.setStartRow(#_445);
scanRequest.setStartRow(#_446);
scanRequest.setCaching(1000);
scanRequest.setFilter(filterListForAmounts);
```

I would appreciate if someone can help in optimizing this.